# python logging ensure a handler is added only once

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a piece of code that is initializing a logger as below.

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Unfortunately this code is being called multiple times, is there any way I can check to see if the handler already exists - I'd prefer to implement this without having to use a Singleton.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention this is on python 2.5 - cheers, Richard

Comment: I think you should reevaluate the answers, because mouad's answer (at time of writing) ignores the fact that multiple calls to a method returning the same logger object *CAN* add duplicate handlers. narayan does a good job of explaining this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As @offbyone comments, it is possible to add redundant handlers to the same instance of the logger.
The [python docs for logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) say-

> "Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will return a
>   reference to the same logger object."

So we don't need to worry about making the implementation a singleton, as it already is.

Unfortunately the same is **not true** for the handlers associated with the same instance of the logger. There *can* be duplicate handlers attached.

Example-

1. Copy this code and save it in main.py

   ```
   import logging
   print 'inside main.py',
   print '-'*50
   def logger():

         print 'initializing logger....'
         logPath = '.'
         fileName = 'temp'

         # configure log formatter
         logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(filename)s] [%(funcName)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(lineno)d] %(message)s")

         # configure file handler
         fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName))
         fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

         # configure stream handler
         consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
         consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

         # get the logger instance
         logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

         # set the logging level
         logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

         print 'adding handlers- '

         #if not len(logger.handlers):
         logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
         logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

         print 'logger initialized....\n'
         print 'associated handlers - ', len(logger.handlers)
         for handler in logger.handlers:
               print handler
         print
         return logger

   main_logger = logger()
   main_logger.info('utilizing main.py logger.')
   print 'exiting main.py',
   print '-'*50
   ```
2. and the following code in sub.py

   ```
   print 'inside sub.py',
   print '-'*50
   print 'importing main.py'
   import main
   print 'imported main.py'
   import logging
   print 'getting logger instance in sub'
   sub_logger = main.logger()
   print 'got logger instance in sub'
   sub_logger.info("utilizing sub_logger")
   print 'exiting sub.py',
   print '-'*50
   ```
3. Run sub.py

   ```
   narayan@y510p:~/code/so$ python sub.py
   inside sub.py --------------------------------------------------
   importing main.py
   inside main.py --------------------------------------------------
   initializing logger....
   adding handlers- 
   logger initialized....

   associated handlers -  2
   <logging.FileHandler object at 0x7f7158740c90>
   <logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f7158710b10>

   2015-08-04 07:41:01,824 [main.py] [<module>] [INFO] [41] utilizing main.py logger.
   exiting main.py --------------------------------------------------
   imported main.py
   getting logger instance in sub
   initializing logger....
   adding handlers- 
   logger initialized....

   associated handlers -  4 # <===== 4 handlers (duplicates added)
   <logging.FileHandler object at 0x7f7158740c90>
   <logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f7158710b10>
   <logging.FileHandler object at 0x7f7158710bd0>
   <logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7f7158710c10>

   got logger instance in sub
   2015-08-04 07:41:01,824 [sub.py] [<module>] [INFO] [10] utilizing sub_logger
   2015-08-04 07:41:01,824 [sub.py] [<module>] [INFO] [10] utilizing sub_logger
   exiting sub.py --------------------------------------------------
   ```

Hence multiple calls to the method returning the same logger added duplicate handlers.

Now, for your question-

> is there any way I can check to see if the handler already exists

Yes, there is-

`logger.handlers` returns a list of all the handlers associated with the given `logger`.

Before adding handlers to an instance of the logger, make sure not to add duplicate handlers
    In main.py, just un-comment the line that says `if not len(logger.handlers):` and indent the following two lines properly-

```
if not len(logger.handlers):
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

Now again run sub.py

```
narayan@y510p:~/code/so$ python sub.py
inside sub.py --------------------------------------------------
importing main.py
inside main.py --------------------------------------------------
initializing logger....
adding handlers- 
logger initialized....

associated handlers -  2
<logging.FileHandler object at 0x7fd67a891c90>
<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7fd67a862b10>

2015-08-04 08:14:45,620 [main.py] [<module>] [INFO] [41] utilizing main.py logger.
exiting main.py --------------------------------------------------
imported main.py
getting logger instance in sub
initializing logger....
adding handlers- 
logger initialized....

associated handlers -  2 # <===== Still 2 handlers (no duplicates)
<logging.FileHandler object at 0x7fd67a891c90>
<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7fd67a862b10>

got logger instance in sub
2015-08-04 08:14:45,620 [sub.py] [<module>] [INFO] [10] utilizing sub_logger
exiting sub.py --------------------------------------------------
```

Further, if you want to limit the type of handlers to be added to the logger instance, you can do something like this-

```
    print 'adding handlers- '
    # allows to add only one instance of file handler and stream handler
    if len(logger.handlers) > 0:
        print 'making sure we do not add duplicate handlers'
        for handler in logger.handlers:
              # add the handlers to the logger
              # makes sure no duplicate handlers are added

              if not isinstance(handler, logging.FileHandler) and not isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler):
                    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
                    print 'added file handler'
                    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
                    print 'added stream handler'
    else:
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
        print 'added handlers for the first time'
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

> Unfortunately the same is **not true** for the handlers associated
>   with the same instance of the logger. There *can* be duplicate
>   handlers attached.

It turns out that that above statement is not entirely true.

Let's suppose we have created and configured a logger called *'main_logger'* in the main module (which simply configures the logger, doesn't return anything).

```
# get the logger instance
logger = logging.getLogger("main_logger")
# configuration follows
...
```

Now in a sub-module, if we create a child logger following the naming hierarchy *'main_logger.sub_module_logger'*, we don't need to configure it in the sub-module. Just creation of the logger following the naming hierarchy is sufficient.

```
# get the logger instance
logger = logging.getLogger("main_logger.sub_module_logger")
# no configuration needed
# it inherits the configuration from the parent logger
...
```

And it won't add duplicate handler as well.

Reference- [Using logging in multiple modules](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)

Comment: This is definitively the best answer. mouad's answer is unfortunately shortsighted in that it misses the possibility of duplicate handlers (not singletons) for a single instance of a logger (the singleton). Your answer helped me solve my problem.

Comment: "logger.handlers returns a list of all the handlers associated with the given logger"  ... yes it does, but can I ask you how you found this out?  Did you go back to the source code?  Because the python logging module documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html does not reveal this info.  Sometimes I feel Python's standard documentation is a bit lacking... anything better you could recommend?

Comment: @mikerodent I found about _logger.handlers_  on SO when I was struggling with this duplicate output issue in logging and verified the same in the source code. Regarding documentation, more often than not, the standard docs do the job.  [pymotw](https://pymotw.com/2/contents.html) helps me whenever I want something specific to be done with the help of python standard library.

Comment: Thank you very much, your (great btw) answer helped me a lot.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.12, logging-0.5.1.2. I initialize a logger in my main module and add a `StreamHandler`. In a different module, I then create another logger instance using `logger2 = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Then `logger2.handlers` returns `[]`. I needed to do `logger2.root.handlers` to check for handlers. FYI.

Answer (score 18):

Well the [logger.addHandler()](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler) will not add a handler if the handler already exists.  To check if the handler is already there you can check the logger.handlers list:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print logger.handlers
# [<logging.FileHandler object at 0x14542d0>]
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
print logger.handlers
# [<logging.FileHandler object at 0x14542d0>]
```

Beside that I will suggest putting this code in your main() function if you have one or in the `__init__.py` file of your package so to not have to call it each time.  I will also suggest that you use a named logger, and do not use the root logger.  Something like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: is the `Logger.handlers' list documented anywhere? I could not find it on http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: @MariuszPluciński: Yeah i don't think it's documented anywhere, but if i remember well i had to check the Logger class code to understand how this work: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/482590320549/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1215

Comment: But if it's undocumented, then it may silently disappear in some future version of logging library. I'm not sure if it's good to depend on this feature (but I agree that, there doesn't seem to be any documented way to check this).

Comment: This isn't entirely correct, as it is possible to add the same *type* of handler multiple times:  [I know the comment formatting is gruesome]>>> log = logging.getLogger()
>>> hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> hndl = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> hdlr
<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10e077ed0>
>>> hndl
<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10e167150>
>>> log.addHandler(hdlr)
>>> log.addHandler(hndl)
>>> log.handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10e077ed0>, <logging.StreamHandler object at 0x10e167150>]

Answer (score 6):

You can also just check to see whether the handler list is empty. Here's the solution I wound up with:

```
def setup_logging(self, logfile):
    self._logger = logging.getLogger('TestSuite')
    self._logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    host = socket.gethostname().split('.')[0]
    if self._logger.handlers == []:
        fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile,
                                                  maxBytes=10*1024*1024,
                                                  backupCount=5)
        strfmt = "%" + "(asctime)s [%s] " % host + "%" + "(message)s"
        fmt = logging.Formatter(strfmt, datefmt="%Y.%m%d %H:%M:%S")
        fh.setFormatter(fmt)

        self._logger.addHandler(fh)
    self._logger.info('-' * (55 - len(host)))
```

I was seeing the handler added multiple times, so each log message was getting written to the log file more than once, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with AWS Lambda, then you might already know that in some contexts, the handlers come pre-configured [1]. Assuming `logger.handlers` is not empty, is not enough. I recommend setting an attribute on the logger instance, like so:

```py
def init_logger(logger):
    if hasattr(logger, 'initialized'):
        return logger  # No need for addHandler
    else:
        setattr(logger, 'initialized', True)

    # Initialize the logger
    # ...
```

[1] [Using python Logging with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703609/using-python-logging-with-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if `logger` is already set. For example, if this code is inside a function:

```
logger = None
def init_logger():
    global logger
    if logger is not None:
        #logger has already been initialized
        return
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I guess the check `if logger is not None` is not thread safe so there's no guarantee the initialization code won't run more than once.