# Why is this logging config duplicating records?

Tags: python, django, logging

Trying to log the SQL queries from django and I've been successful (in spades).  Every log record is duplicated.  How do I make it log only once?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s P%(process)d T%(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail-admins'],
        'level': "ERROR",
        'propagate': True,
    },
    '': {
        'level': "ERROR",
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
    },
    'django.db': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': "DEBUG",
    }
},

'handlers': {
    'default':{
        'level': "ERROR",
        'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    'mail-admins': {
        'level': "ERROR",
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
   'logfile': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'logs', 'project.log'),
        'maxBytes': 1000000,
        'backupCount': 5,
        'formatter': 'verbose',
    },
}
}
```

The log lines all start like this (every line appears twice, remainder removed for clarity):

```
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,430 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,430 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,432 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,432 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,433 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,433 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,436 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,436 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,439 util P17718 T140208802572032 
DEBUG 2014-02-02 08:52:25,439 util P17718 T140208802572032
```

Comment: Is this on target? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173033/duplicate-log-output-when-using-python-logging-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the section

```
'': {
    'level': "ERROR",
    'handlers': ['logfile'],
},
```

which means that although only `ERROR` or greater levels will be handled by the root logger, messages from loggers lower in the hierarchy will be passed to handlers of the root logger. So a message logged to the `django.db` logger will be passed to any handlers attached to the
`django` logger and the root logger (parent of the `django` logger).

See [this diagram](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for more information on how information flows in the logging system.

Comment: Added `'propagate': False,` to the django.db section and that fixed it.