# logging to different files in different module

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm trying to write a file python modules and I need to log the output of different module to different files.

module_a.py

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(levle = logging.INFO, filename="a.log")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def function_a():
    logger.info("this is function a")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("this is module a")
    function_a()
```

module_b.py

```
import logging
import module_a

logging.basicConfig(levle = logging.INFO, filename="b.log")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def function_b():
    module_a.function_a()
    logger.info("this is function b")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("this is module b")
    function_b()
```

What I want to do is, I wants module_b.py always log to b.log, and
module_a.py always log to a.log, no matter the module was called or imported and then called.

The issue I got now is,

If I run

```
python3 module_a.py
```

All good.

If I run

```
python3 module_b.py
```

then all logs will be logged into a.log. I understand when import module_a, logger got overwritten. So how can make sure these two modules can always log into the right files?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the advice here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495083/using-python-logging-from-multiple-modules-with-writing-to-a-file-and-rotatingfi

Comment: @Andrew-Harelson I don't have a main file. So I could not define the handler in main.py.  That's why make log configure a little bit difficult.

Comment: 2 things. When you run `python3 module_b.py`, then mobdule_b.py is your main file. There's no reason your main file has to be named main.py. Second, defining your handlers in your main file is just best practice, not a hard rule. If you have some kind of constraint where you can't modify the main file, you can always just setup your handlers in the module.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, logging rules are decided by top level scripts. Imported modules just log without worrying about where the logs go. You want something different. So stay clear of `basicConfig` which is just a helper, and have each module setup its own logger.

In this example, I pulled the setup into a function. Its an easy way to get rid of temporary variables like `handler`. You may want to add a formatter while you are at it. The function is the same in both scripts. You may want to pull it into a single common utilities module. Or maybe there is a reason to do things differently in different modules. There are so many ways to setup loggers that the function is really just a rough guess of what you'll do in your project.

module_a

```
import logging

def make_logger(name):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=name + ".log")
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger

logger = make_logger("a")

def function_a():
    logger.info("this is function a")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("this is module a")
    function_a()
```

module_b

```
import logging
import module_a

def make_logger(name):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=name + ".log")
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    return logger

logger = make_logger("b")

def function_b():
    module_a.function_a()
    logger.info("this is function b")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("this is module b")
    function_b()
```